# How to split a sentence in python and put in list?

Tags: python, list, split

I made string called artist:

```
artist = "Kanye West and Taylor Swift"
artistName = []
```

I want to split variable from "and" and append them in to artistName.

So output will be = `['Kanye', 'West', 'Taylor', 'Swift']`

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you've written to address your issue?  Hint: start here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Please look at [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.

Answer (score 3):

```
[x for x in artist.split() if x!= 'and']
```

Comment: This still doesn't give what OP wants, as he wants each word split as well. Also, your answer can be summed down to: split("and")

Comment: This gives exactly what the OP asked for, and is until now the only answer that doesn't fail if an artist name contains 'and'...

Comment: Oh yes sorry it does

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to split:

```
artist = "Kanye West and Taylor Swift sheriand"
artistName = artist.split()
finalList=[]
for name in artistName:
    if name == "and":
        continue
    else:
        finalList.append(name)
print(finalList)
```

Comment: This will include "and" as an entry in the output list, which is not desired.

Comment: Bad idea... What if the name of an artist contains 'and', like Randy?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille yes it make sense

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Using a regex match would be best, but for this simplistic case the above solution is sufficient.

Comment: Now the code is worked as expected even a name contain "and" as sub-string. it cannot remove the name which contain "and"

Answer (score 1):

replace the and with empty string and then split

```
string ="Kanye West and Taylor Swift".replace(' and ', ' ').replace(' and', '').split()
print(string)
```

this also works with regex

```
import re
string = re.sub('(^and) | \s*and\s*', ' ', string).split()
print(string)
```

Comment: Bad idea... What if the name of an artist contains 'and', like Randy?

Comment: Added an extra space around the string "and" before replace,  with an space and then split to fix the issue when "and" is part of artist name, this another way to solve the problem ,  but I personally recommend answer suggested by @Lior Cohen

Answer (score -1):

I recommend reading the [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) for python's split() function. To get your desired output, you will need to use split twice - once on 'and' and again with ' '.

```
artist = "Kanye West and Taylor Swift"
output = artist.split("and")
# Output looks like: ["Kanye West", "Taylor Swift"]
```

You could then iterate over each name in your list and split them by ' '. (I'll leave the exact implementation up to you.)